# struts <logic:equal > inside a <logic:iterate>

Tags: struts

I'm using struts `logic:iterate` and I want to do something different if my `indexId` is equal to `1`   but I can't figure out a logic combination to say if  indexId == 1  do something.

there is a way to use `<logic:equal>` on the `indexId` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use JSTL over the S1 tags when functionality overlaps.
2. Doesn't `<logic:equal name="nameOfIndexIdVar" value="1"/>` work?